# No view found for fragment in 1. Nav Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hello guys I created 2 navigation drawers and like 2 main activties in my app (1 for logged users and other for not logged users). Now when user Login and want to see news it works great it open a new fragment where is a list of news and when user choose particular news it open it's details and it's working awesome. But problem is when I open news detail in activity for not logged users. I manage to isolate a problem it's here.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int      position, long id) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = new DetailView();
    Integer ID;
    ID = listNovosti.get(position).getId();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("ID", ID);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragmentlayout, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Problem is in this line :

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragmentlayout, fragment);
```

I'm using 2 frags layout 1 for logged users (fragmentprelayout) and second is fragmentlayout.

How can i adjust or do some magic around that ft.replace so that It can choose between those 2 layouts?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, `int layoutId = findViewById(R.id.fragmentlayout) == null ? R.id.fragmentprelayout: R.id.fragmentlayout;`. Though, I'm not sure why you just don't use the same ID in both layouts, if only one is going to be loaded at a time.

Comment: I would really like to use same layout for both frags but when I try that I got this error : 
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ba.lampica.dev/lampica.ba.lampica.views.activities.MainPreLogin}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00b7 (ba.lampica.dev:id/fragmentlayout) for fragment LoginFragment{26f5ec3e #0 id=0x7f0d00b7}

Again about no view found for id.. :/

Comment: I'm not really clear on your setup, so if the above doesn't work for you, you'll need to provide more details, like the layouts, and the relevant code from the Activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way would be you create different fragments and launch them similarly from both activities but if you still want to use the same fragment

Here is how you can achieve that

First you need to check which activity is running by using a Boolean

So in fragment you need a variable like

```
public static Boolean running = false;

class LoginActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     Fragment.running = true;
  }
}
```

we will change the fragment layout on its launch
that is if `LoginActivity` is running then `iflate.LayoutforLoginActivity.xml` else `iflate.layoutforNonLoginActivty.xml`

So in OnCreateView of DetailViewFragment we will do so like this

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;

    if(running) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.LayoutforLoginActivity, container, false);
    }else {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.LayoutforNonLoginActivity, container, false);

    }
```

This is just a hack,

**in this case your both xml must have same ids for all the views otherwise you will get `NullPointerException`**